# query SELECT COUNT only unique values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to count the rows in selected table

```
$queryvps = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM vpss";  
$resultvps = mysql_query($queryvps) or die(mysql_error()); 
foreach(mysql_fetch_array($resultvps) as $vpscount);
```

I need to count results from another table but they are not unique, how to count duplicate results once?

Comment: *"I need to count results from another table but they are not unique"* - what "other" table? Your question is unclear and stands at being closed because of it.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Above are most likely not being viewed *Sam* - @JayBlanchard - posted mine 7 mins. prior to this; waste of time, I think.

Comment: *"I need to count results from **another table**"* - explain that, if you're bothering looking at the comments here.

Comment: I need to count results from Coulmn under name Username. But most of them are not unique.  example: http://gyazo.com/cec6b0c3510b563dbc353345f904cd86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the keyword DISTINCT in your query.  For example:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Username)) FROM vpss;

Comment: Prints "1"

Here is what kind of data i store in my Table http://gyazo.com/a3b47f044a9a865527e34b256292a02a

Comment: What was your query?

Comment: $querytotal = "SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM vpss";  
$resulttotal = mysql_query($querytotal) or die(mysql_error()); 
foreach(mysql_fetch_array($resulttotal) as $usertotal);

Comment: Try "select distinct username from vpss"; What are the results?

Comment: Result is the first Value in this case HunT3R

Comment: Something must be wrong in the way you're parsing the results.  Are you looping through the result set to get the results?  Because I know 100% that this is the correct answer.  Post your code to parse the query results.

Comment: $querytotal = "SELECT DISTINCT(Username) FROM vpss";  
$resulttotal = mysql_query($querytotal) or die(mysql_error()); 
foreach(mysql_fetch_array($resulttotal) as $usertotal);


This is the query and im printing it with <?php echo $vpscount ?>

Comment: I see, you're looking for an integer not the results to work with? Ok use:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Username)) FROM vpss;  

Post me the number result.

Comment: Thats what i need! Thanks sir! the result is now 6 and correct. I wish i can vote up :D

Comment: I'm just going to edit the answer so it reflects the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use group by.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vpss GROUP BY `Username`
```

Comment: @Devion ID's are not unique :/

Comment: Give some sample data.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/a3b47f044a9a865527e34b256292a02a

There you go

Comment: @CEED, so you use username instead of ID?  You couldn't figure that out on your own?

Comment: the code is premade. My knowladge in PHP is really low.
I need to count unique usernames in the Table and print them as number.

Comment: That is what this does...

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct in the query 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM vpss